# Stage in Persist has only 1 task running causing spill to disk

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are caching a data set after running the given SQL on it. The flow of the code is

1. Load the dataset into a spark data frame
2. Run SQL
3. Repartition the result dataset using `dataset.repartition()`
4. and cache the dataset with option `MEMORY_AND_DISK`.

The SQL to run is :

```
`select *,CASE WHEN event_type in ('value1','value2') THEN EXISTING_COLUMN_1 ELSE '0' END AS NEW_COLUMN_NAME from events`
```

The result of the SQL is another data frame- result, that we repartition using `result.repartion(300)` and cache it by using persist function. The parameter `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is set to 2001.

Now, the problem is, at the time of caching, there are three stages:
[![`stages`][1]][1]

- stage 1 shuffle-writes the data
- stage 2 shuffle-reads it. There is no spill to disk/memory in these stages
- stage 3, in which there is only 1 task running and causing spill to disk and memory. This has become the bottleneck in our application. [![`stage3`][2]][2]
  [![enter image description here][3]][3]

Why there is this stage with one task, which is spilling the data to disk/memory?  Kindly help us in understanding the issue and where we are going wrong.

Edit 1: Code snippet for Function_SQLTransformation.scala with SQL.

```
val events=spark.read.format("orc").load("path")
val table=spark.sql("""select *,
                     CASE 
                     WHEN event_type in ('value1','value2') THEN 
                     EXISTING_COLUMN_1 ELSE '0'
                     END AS NEW_COLUMN_NAME from events""".stripMargin)
table = table.repartition(300)
table.createOrReplaceTempView("second_table_name")
table.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcAZt.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l723E.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUE3G.png
```

Comment: You'd probably want to share `Function_SQLTransformation.scala` code to get any help..

Comment: not enough info here

Comment: Can you show the SQL queries for this?

Comment: I have updated the SQL and code snippet for Function_SQLTransformation.scala. Please let us know if anything is not clear in the question. Thank you.